# illegal switch in RUBYOPT: -E (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8, codekit

I keep getting this error in codekit when trying to compile my project and have no idea what it means:

```
System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: illegal switch in RUBYOPT: -E (RuntimeError)
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This guide should help you:**

http://www.amyhaywood.com/problems-codekit-upgrading-mavericks/

...

If not, fixes to the issue discussed in the CodeKit forum:

https://github.com/bdkjones/CodeKit/issues/686

> You’re on Mavericks and you’ve got CodeKit set to use an external
>   Compass, Sass, Slim or Haml compiler. But that external compiler is
>   running in the old version of Ruby that was migrated from Mountain
>   Lion (Ruby 1.8.7).
>
> All you need to do is re-install your external compiler in the Ruby
>   2.0 environment on Mavericks and use that compiler instead. Alternately, you can simply switch CodeKit back to using its internal
>   compiler.

Run

```
sudo gem install ruby
sudo gem install compass
```

Answer (score 0):

`-E` in Ruby 2+ means:

```
-Eex[:in]       specify the default external and internal character encodings
```

It isn't an option in Ruby 1.8 which is why you get the error, so you can either upgrade your Ruby (using RVM or rbenv since you're on Mac OS), or change your settings to not include `-E`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I checked the latest version of ruby and it says I have the latest version installed (2.0.0p247) so I'm not sure why it's saying version 1.8 in the codekit error message.

Comment: CodeKit is using a built-in version of Ruby. You have to contact the developer: https://github.com/bdkjones/CodeKit/issues